# 500 Error for accessing static resources: Play Framework

Tags: java, playframework

I have downloaded a Play project of my company. I have build it perfectly but when i run it, its routes working perfectly for `scala.html` pages but wherever i try to access static resources from my app it gives me `500` Error. Below is my setting in `routes` file:
`GET     /app/assets/*file                                  controllers.Assets.at(path="/public", file)`

And the way i am trying to access static resournces from templates:
`<link rel="stylesheet" href="@routes.Assets.at("stylesheets/bootstrap.min.css")">`

What i think is there is some issue when `Scala` is compiling templates and try to attach static resources in template it fails and give `500`. But the version of Scala of mine and my colleagues are same. There is nothing visible in `log` as well. Below is my screenshot of Firebug:
[image]

The only difference what i can see is i am using Java 8, and my colleagues are using Java 7. But i don't think it will effect much.

Comment: Every asset request has the same size, so probably you are receiving a HTTP 500 error and an html page with a description of the error instead of the asset. Try to get that and add it to your question. Also aren't you getting any exception in the console when you try to access that page?

Answer (score 0):

I think there is an issue with your URL, By default when working with public assets the route will look like following.

`GET    /assets/*file      controllers.Assets.at(path="/public", file)`

As per play [documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/Assets), when you want to access the static resource under public directory your URL should be `/assets/*file` so play will look for the requested resource like following `public/stylesheets/bootstrap.min.css`

So try to replace the URL from  `/app/assets/*file` to `/assets/*file`